# OS X - Disable password prompt for specific application (AMPPS)

Tags: macos, passwords, ampps

I would love to figure out how to disable the admin password prompt for a specific application (AMPPS). I use  AMPPS for local development, and it is constantly asking for my admin password every time I start/stop Apache, MySQL, etc. Typing in my password dozens of times over the course of a day gets pretty annoying.

I understand the need for security and appreciate that OS X does this in general, but in this case it's pretty useless and annoying.

Any ideas of a way to tell OS X that this application is OK to do what it needs to do?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent AMPPS from prompting password on every start/stop command:

```
Run Terminal
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Go to the bottom of the file and append these two lines (replace **username** with your short username, obtained by typing **whoami** on a new terminal window):

```
%username ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/Ampps.app
%username ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Press <kbd>Y</kbd>

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the info! @aliem is right though; the top of the file mentions this too. The following link has some info on how to accomplish this, and concise info on how to edit the file using the rather quirky vim: https://maeks84.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/how-to-use-visudo/